# javascript not working in ajax div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a very basic bit of ajax coding However the javaScript is not working inside the AJAX loaded DIV. Id like to get the slider and the masonry within the pages to work.

Here is my ajax code.

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Establish Variables
    var
        History = window.History, // Note: Using a capital H instead of a lower h
        State = History.getState(),
        $log = $('#log');

    // If the link goes to somewhere else within the same domain, trigger the pushstate
    $('#access a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var path = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $(this).text();
        History.pushState('ajax',title,path);
    });

    // Bind to state change
    // When the statechange happens, load the appropriate url via ajax
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() { // Note: Using statechange instead of popstate
        load_site_ajax();
    });

    // Load Ajax
    function load_site_ajax() {
        State = History.getState(); // Note: Using History.getState() instead of event.state
        // History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);
        //console.log(event);
        $("#primary").prepend('<div id="ajax-loader"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>');
        $("#ajax-loader").fadeIn();
        $('#site-description').fadeTo(200,0);
        $('#content').fadeTo(200,.3);
        $("#main").load(State.url + ' #primary, #secondary', function(data) {
            /* After the content loads you can make additional callbacks*/
            $('#site-description').text('Ajax loaded: ' + State.url);
            $('#site-description').fadeTo(200,1);
            $('#content').fadeTo(200,1);

            // Updates the menu
            var request = $(data);
            $('#access').replaceWith($('#access', request));

        });
    }   
});
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: @isherwood The slider on one of the pages won't work when the page loads within the ajax container. It however works great when you load the page directly.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins such as sliders won't work in dynamically-derived elements such as tabs, accordions, and ajax elements unless you initialize them after the container element is shown or created.

Run your slider init function as a `success` callback to the ajax function.